Serialize/ Deserialize ID instead of object in cereal
I want to serialize structs using cereal. One of them looks like this:
struct Material {
  std::shared_ptr<Texture> texture1;
  std::shared_ptr<Texture> texture2;
};

In my program, Textures are managed by a TextureManager:
class Texture {
  std::string id_; // Guaranteed to be unique
};

class TextureManager {
public:
  std::shared_ptr<Texture> get_texture_by_id(std::string_view id);

private:
  std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Texture>> textures_;
};

I would like cereal to serialize these textures as their IDs, and have it use the TextureManager to load them.
{
  "texture1": "/assets/dog.bmp",
  "texture2": "/assets/foo.jpg"
}

Is this possible? If yes: How?

Did you read "specializing the type" in the documentation?

@Botje Thanks, exactly what I needed. I had skimmed over this part of the docs, but didn't think it'd apply. If you want, you can write an answer and I'll accept it, otherwise I'll just post an answer myself.

I solved this by specializing save and load for std::shared_ptr, as suggested by @Botje:
namespace cereal {

template <class Archive>
void save(Archive& archive, const std::shared_ptr<Texture>& ptr)
{
    archive(make_nvp("id", std::string(ptr->get_id()))); // Store just the ID
}

template <class Archive>
void load(Archive& archive, std::shared_ptr<Texture>& ptr)
{
    std::string id;
    archive(make_nvp("id", id));

    ptr = TextureManager::get().get_texture_by_id(id);
}

}

